# Probability winning a lottery with supplementary numbers.

Tags: probability

For a particular lottery a player picks a selection of 6 numbers from the numbers 1 to 45. To determine the winners 8 numbers are chosen at random. The first 6 are designated as the winning numbers and the other 2 as supplementary numbers. Prizes are determined as follows;

Div 1: 6 winning numbers

Div 2: 5 winning numbers + 1 suplementary

Div 3: 5 winning numbers

Div 4: 4 winning numbers

Div 1 is simple enough just the number of combinations and I understand that Div 3 is actually 5 winning numbers and 0 supplementary. Div 4 is also 4 winning numbers plus any amount of supplementary. But I'm unsure the methodology to calculate Div 2.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are $6$ ways to choose the five of your numbers that will be winning and $39$ ways to choose a winning number that you didn't pick.  Then the supplementary number you picked is determined and there are $38$ ways to choose the supplementary number you didn't pick.  Overall the chance is then $$\frac{6 \cdot 39 \cdot 38}{{45 \choose 6}{39 \choose 2}}=\frac 1{678755}$$

Comment: this assumes sequential picking? I would think they picked the 8 out of 45 in $\binom{45}{8}$ ways?

Comment: @sku:  It was defined that there were six picked as winning and two as supplementary numbers, so we have to pick one batch and then the other from what is left.